# Keep AlertDialog's DialogInterface opened

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom AlertDialog where a user has to set password. There are two edittext views.
I compare them first if they match and if they are more than 3 characters long. If they don't match, I display a toast to alert the user. But after submitting and checking the dialog closes. How can I keep it opened until user inserts the correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking at doing something similar and I could not find a way do this with the standard AlertDialog as it is.

One possible way I found was to not specify any button listeners in your AlertDialog and instead place a view with your own custom buttons that perform the checks and then dismiss the dialog if necessary. I've not yet tried this to see how it works.

Another option is to create your own Custom dialog by subclassing Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a global variable like

```
boolean showAlert = true;
```

And attach a onClick listener to the AlertDialog and after cheking to see if there is need to show the alert again. If there is a need, you should show it again. You can`t keep it open if the user clicks a button from the AlertDialog. You have to recreate it again.

Comment: fyi: recreating of the dialog doesn't work. if you call showDialog() inside the onClick of the dialog, its simply ignored.

Comment: @WarrenFaith By recreating I mean creating a new object of AlertDialog.

Comment: I know that. I tried to look for a way to create a new object of the dialog when calling showDialog(). I just used dismissDialog() to dismiss it, but calling showDialog() again doesn't create a new object of the dialog. I had to use removeDialog() which removes any internal reference to the dialog so that showDialog() creates a new object. Thats all I tried to say :)